# control image visibility in repeater based on session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, session-variables

I'm having trouble figuring out how to control the visibility of an image in a gridview based on a session variable.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgImportedData" Width="20px" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/images/warning.png" CausesValidation="false"   />
```

I tried using `Visible='<%# mySessionVariable %>'` but I got a message saying mySessionVariable was unavailable.  I think this is because it's in a grid because I am using this variable in the code behind for another part of the page outside of the gridview without any problems.

EDIT:  I just realized this in a `Repeater` control and not a `GridView`.

I tried both of these and still get `The name 'MySession' does not exist in the current context`

```
Visible='<%# (bool)MySession.IsImportedData == "true" ? true : false %>' 

Visible='<%# MySession.IsImportedData == "true" ? true : false %>'
```

Comment: Is `MySession` a class that you created? Can you access it from the code-behind?

Comment: yes I can access is from the code behind.  I'm using in the page load event to determine whether or not to disply a label and it works there.  it's a static class.

Answer (score 1):

`<%#` is a DataBinding ASP server tag. What happens when you change `<%#` to `<%=`?

If that doesn't work, I would suggest setting the column's visibility in a `RowDataBound` event, like so:

```
MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image imgImportedData = (Image) e.Row.FindControl("imgImportedData");

        // Assuming that mySessionVariable isn't already a bool, which it really should be.
        imgImportedData.Visible = bool.Parse(mySessionVariable);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i use = i get Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation

Comment: If you post more specific code about mySessionVariable, I can help. It's possible that you just need `(bool) mySessionVariable`.

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald: then try: `Visible='<%= bool.Parse(Session["mySessionVariable"])%>'`

Comment: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= bool.Parse(Session["MySession.IsImportedData"])%>' for the 'Visible' property.

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald I'm not exactly sure what you're trying here. You said above that MySession is a static class. How are you putting `IsImportedData` in `MySession`? How are you putting it in the Session? If you have a static class that's already accessing Session data, you don't need to re-access the Session data for the Parse routine.

Comment: MySession.IsImportedData is populated from a Session variable conIsImportedData

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald, okay, it sounds to me like you need **either**: `imgImportedData.Visible = MySession.IsImportedData;` ***OR*** `imgImportedData.Visible = bool.Parse(Session["conIsImportedData"]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgImportedData" 
    Visible='<%# Session["mySessionVariable"] == "foo" ? true : false %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work.  Thank you for everyone's help.  I found an example on this page that helped.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx

```
 protected void rptAlternateNames_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
            {

                Image imageImportedData = ((Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgImportedData"));
                if (MySession.IsImportedData)
                {
                    imageImportedData.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For brevity's sake, you should really combine your if statement to one line that says: `imageImportedData.Visible = MySession.IsImportedData`.